# How To check Product Have Variation in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Is there any way to check the product has variation something like 
Please help me.

```
<?php 
If (product has variation) {
   echo"This Product have Variations ";
} else {
   echo "This Product does not have Variations ";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should work:

```
if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
    // No variations to product 
} elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
   // Product has variations
}
```

Example:
If you will replace the file woocommerce --> single-product --> meta.php with this code, you will see it works.

```
<?php
/**
* Single Product Meta
*
* @author       WooThemes
* @package  WooCommerce/Templates
* @version     1.6.4
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $product;

$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
$tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );
?>
<div class="product_meta">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

<?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>

    <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php _e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku" itemprop="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>.</span>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>

<?php echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>
<?php if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
// No variations to product 
echo "XX";
} elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
// Product has variations 
echo "VV";
} ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I have Try this but it does not work . See Below code

Comment: Checking it now, will let you know a few minutes.

Comment: It works. Are you putting the code inside the loop of product? In which file?

Comment: This is my another question describe full context please check when you have time. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851886/if-product-has-variation-disable-the-quantity-in-woocommerce-mini-cart)

Comment: Its a link to the same question.

Comment: This does not check if the product has variations, this checks the product type. The product could still have no variations.

Comment: How can I show product **NOT** is_type('my_product_type') ??

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($product->is_type('simple')) { 
    // Simple product
} elseif ($product->is_type('grouped')) {
   // Grouped product
} elseif ($product->is_type( 'external')) {
   // External/Affiliate product
} elseif ($product->is_type('variable')) {
   // Variable product
}
```

To get all variation ids of a variable product

```
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$variations_id = wp_list_pluck( $variations, 'variation_id' );
```

The above code will provide visible variation ids only. For example, If the price is not set for a variation, that variation will be hidden.

Alternatively use the below code to get all variations without considering visibility.

```
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
$current_products = $product->get_children();
```